# Add a layer on top of an image that has priority over the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a Chrome extension which stops all requests of images and will allow you to click on the broken image icon in order to load the image without the blocking. This is in order to save bandwidth.

I have setup the request blocking but I'm not sure how to go about the next step.

The next step would be adding a layer on top of that broken image icon which would intercept any clicks on that image. The reason I do this is because often an image will be anchored to another link so clicking on it would do something else to what is desired.

I thought of perhaps using the `z-index` CSS rule but I'm not entirely sure of how this works and also I'm not sure if this would be the best way to go about this.

Any suggestions? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css to your html

```
<style type="text/css">
  //container div 
     .container{
      width:300px;
      position:relative; 
      }
 //image css property
  .imageHolder{
      position:absolute; 
      left:0px; 
      top:0px; 
      width:100%; 
      height:100%; 
      z-index:10px;
      }
  //    overlay css property
  .imageOverlay{
      position: absolute; 
      z-index:11px; 
      top:0px; 
      left:0px; 
      width:100%; height:100%; 
      text-align:center;
      }
  </style>
```

This is your html code will be

```
<div class="container">

    <img src="myimage.png" class="imageHolder" />

    <div class="imageOverlay"> Load </div>

</div>
```

Hope it helps... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you'll have to do something like:

- create a base div with css relative position
- create your img tag with css absolute position, left:0px, top:0px, width:100%, height probably 50 and z-index probably 10.
- create a top layer div with css position:absolute, z-index higher than that of the img, top:0px, left:0px, width: 100px and height probably 50.

The Code would look like

```
<div style="position:relative; width:50px;">

    <img src="image.ext" border="0" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:50px; height:50px; z-index:10px;" />

    <div style="position: absolute; z-index:11px; top:0px; left:0px; width:50px; height:50px; line-height:50px; text-align:center;"> Load </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your answer was also correct Nelson, but Khaja's was better written (I feel) so I accepted his. BTW, welcome to Stack*. :)