# Once an image has failed loading, how can I make the browser retry?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a Chrome extension which in order to reduce bandwidth usage it stops all outcoming requests which are images.

I want to provide functionality where if the user clicks on the image (or technically [a layer on top of that image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26823957/1622940)) it would try to reload the image, this time not being blocked by the extension.

How can I tell the browser to retry loading the image? And if there isn't a straightforward way to do it, what would be a work around? Deleting the old image from the DOM and adding it again?

Any help is appreciated. :)

EDIT 1:

To answer @CBroe's question:

Using the [`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) in a background script.

To answer @jfriend00's question:

The usual placeholder "couldn't load image" icon, I guess also known as "broken file" icon:

[image: broken file icon example]

See all those broken images?

That screenshot also illustrates the point of a layer on top of another image. Should those images not be broken, the loaded image would be there but that layer (the one in a dark grey which shows the image's dimensions) still remains there.

The desired `href` still exists there in the `img` tag:

[image: example of a broken img tag which retains href]

Comment: Well how are you “stopping” those request in the first place?

Comment: And, what is in place of the image in the DOM before it gets clicked on?  It seems like we need to see what is being clicked on and where the desired href is stored.

Comment: @CBroe Added answer to your comment in edit. :)

Comment: @jfriend00 Added answer to your comment in edit. :)

Comment: If simply assigning the same `src` value to the `img` element is not enough, then create a new `Image` object in JavaScript, and assign the value to its `src` property.

Comment: Running some tests, it seems your solution works, @Cbroe. Would you like to answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If simply assigning the same `src` value to the `img` element is not enough¹, then create a new `Image` object in JavaScript, and assign the value to its `src` property.

---

¹  It *might* not be, if the browser just goes, *“oh hey, that is the same value for the `src` attribute that the `img` already had, so I don’t have to do anything”* – creating a new JS `Image` object however should make the browser request that resource again if he realizes he does not have it cached already.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do instead is replace the URLs of the images with an image from your extension.  A 1x1 pixel transparent GIF or PNG.

When you do this, add an attribute to all of the elements you replaced... something like `data-yourextension-originalurl`, with the URL of the original image.  If the user then wants to load images, it's easy enough to go back and fix those image elements.

Comment: This is the way I went with in the end, so although it doesn't answer the original question it is still the most correct answer. Thank you very much. :) I haven't accepted precisely because it doesn't offer the original question though.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not too familiar with the Chrome API, a quick glance seems to suggest that there's no way to get the specific img element from each onBeforeRequest, which you'd need to know in order to figure out where to attach custom code.

This may be better accomplished with native JavaScript of some sort. For example, if Chrome lets you inject code on load, you could apply a function like the one below to all img elements after document load but before image load.

```
// Given an img element, replaces its src with a placeholder URL,
// and sets its click action to load its original src
function makePlaceholder(elem){
    elem["data-oldtitle"] = elem.title;
    elem["data-oldhref"] = elem.href;
    elem["data-oldsrc"] = elem.src;
    elem["data-oldonclick"] = elem.onClick;
    elem.title = "Click to load the blocked image.";
    elem.href = '';
    elem.src = "http://example.com/placeholder.png";
    elem.onClick = function(){
        this.src = this["data-oldsrc"];
        this.title = this["data-oldtitle"];
        this.href = this["data-oldhref"];
        this.onClick = this["data-oldonclick"];
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to force reloading an image in JavaScript is:

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
img.src = img.src.replace(/\?.+/,"") + "?" + new Date().getTime();
```

This adds a unique `QueryString` to the image which basically forces the browser to not use a cached version of the image.

Comment: You don't know that the original query string wasn't required.  Your code blows it away and replaces it with your own.

Comment: @Brad probably unlikely that the original `src` actually specified a query string and the code can be easily adapted to use cases with an original query string.

Comment: I wouldn't call it unlikely at all.  I have worked on several projects and seen many sites where this is commonplace.  You should adapt your code to work properly, so that people don't blindly copy and paste what you have here and break pages.